# Remote control for android using pc with local wifi, without internet

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, supersu, screen-mirroring

I want to control an application in my android mobile using wifi lically. Is there any way to control android device from pc using local wifi or access point without internet !!. I searched alot but all apps need internet .. Also no free vnc server for android .. Please I dont have a problem in rooting my android also I have an old android . Any free app likes vnc can work.

Comment: How old is the Android phone (make/model/OS version)?

Comment: I have Samsung j100h with kitkat 4.2 OS  and j250f with Nughat 7.1 Os.

Comment: https://www.genymotion.com/blog/open-source-project-scrcpy-now-works-wirelessly

Comment: unfortunately scrcpy does support android 5+ but adbcontrol works for kitkat http://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb